# Military hour clock minute

Tags: java

I have to do a problem:

- 00:01 to 5:59 am ( the value would be 1-559 )
- 6:00 to 11:59 am ( the value would be 600-1159 )
- 12:00 noon ( the value would be 1200)
- 12:01 to 17:59 pm ( the value would be 1201-1759 )
- 18:00 to 11:59 hours ( the value would be 1800-2359 )
- 24:00 Midnight ( the value would be 2400)
- Any other value fails.

Here is where I have the problem, you must validate the minutes are not between 60 and 99 if so should display an error (example 470 is an error).

Everything works except for that part. How to fix the code to get that to work?

Here's the code

```
public void tipoHora(int hora){

     if(hora>=1 && hora<=559){
         System.out.println("Madrugada");

     }
     else if (hora>=600 && hora<=1159){
         System.out.println("Mañana");
     }
     else if (hora==1200){
         System.out.println("Medio Dia");
     }
     else if (hora>=1201 && hora<=1759){
         System.out.println("Tarde");
     }
     else if (hora>=1800 && hora<=2359){
         System.out.println("Noche");
     }
     else if (hora==2400){
         System.out.println("Media Noche");
     }
     else {
         System.out.println("Error");
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 if((hora % 100) >= 60) {
     System.out.println("Error");
 }
```

Basically if the 2 least significant digits are equal to or greater than 60 than it is an error.  `%` is the modulus operator; it  will return the remainder of the integer division,  for example `11 % 3` is `2` and `12 % 3` is 0 as `3` divides `12`.  Doing `hora % 100` returns the remainder of dividing `hora` by `100` which gives you the minutes in your case.

Comment: Also, he should validate that before everything else, if not invalid hours will slip through the other ifs